# Cannot convert from 'oncurrentBag<T>' to 'Func<ConcurrentBag<T>>'

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to use a Parallel For loop that will help me speed up the processor intensive calculations and then add those calculations to a thread safe list that I can access after the for loop completes so I can access the data. I followed the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop-with-thread-local-variables

I'm getting a compile time error at the line in bold and since I'm new to multithreading, I would appreciate if you could point out any mistakes that I'm making so I can learn from this error.

```
public static async Task Test()
    {
        Vector<double> vectorArrayBuy = null;
        Vector<double> vectorArraySell = null;
        ConcurrentBag<DailyStockData> query;

        query = new ConcurrentBag<DailyStockData>();
        ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo> listMRInfo = new ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>();                
        Calculations calcTemp = new Calculations();

        **Parallel.For<ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>>(0, 200, (listMRInfo) = new ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>(), (j, loop, listMRInfoLocal) =>**
        {
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(j);
            Calculations calc = new Calculations(query, k);
            var targetValueBuy = calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.MRTargetValueBuy).ToList();
            var targetValueSell = calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.MRTargetValueSell).ToList();
            vectorArrayBuy = CreateVector.Dense(targetValueBuy.ToArray());
            vectorArraySell = CreateVector.Dense(targetValueSell.ToArray());
            var name = calc.ListCalculationData.First();
            ConcurrentBag<double> value;

            value = new ConcurrentBag<double>(calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.WilliamsR));
            MultipleRegressionInfo r1 = Rn(value, vectorArrayBuy, nameof(name.WilliamsR), k, calc);
            listMRInfoLocal.Add(r1);
        calcTemp = calc;

            return listMRInfoLocal;
        },
        (variable) => listMRInfo = variable
        );
listMRInfo = new ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>(listMRInfo.OrderByDescending(i => i.RSquared).DistinctBy(i => i.ValueName).ToList()); // trying to access this data after parallel for loop completes

public class DailyStockData
{
    public DailyStockData();

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal AdjustedClose { get; set; }
    public long Volume { get; set; }
}

public class CalculationData
{
    public CalculationData(CalculationData calcData)
    {
        Date = calcData.Date;
        Open = calcData.Open;
        High = calcData.High;
        Low = calcData.Low;
        Close = calcData.Close;
        AdjustedClose = calcData.AdjustedClose;
        Volume = calcData.Volume;
        WilliamsR = calcData.WilliamsR;
}

    public CalculationData() { }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double AdjustedClose { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double WilliamsR { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a compile-time error, not an exception. It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the custom classes I use but I don't know how to make it run for you without giving you access to my database. What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest you reduce it to a *minimal* example. I very much doubt that most of the code in there is relevant to reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a more complicated overload of the `Parallel.For` function than you need. `listMRinfo` is a concurrent class, so it is safe to directly access this variable within each iteration of the for-loop.

```
Parallel.For<ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>>(0, 200, (index) =>
{
    // ...
    listMRInfo.Add(r1);
});
```

On the other hand, you should not be updating the reference to `calcTemp` within every iteration of the loop without some sort of locking going on. Even with locking, I do not believe you should be storing the value from *one* iteration of the loop. This is a *parallel* foreach, so after the loop has completed, you have no way to guarantee *which iteration* the value of `calcTemp` came from.

Comment: How do you recommend I handle the calcTemp variable?

Comment: I can't say without seeing how it is used. Are you expecting this to be the last calculation of the loop? If so, I would create it _after_ the loop has run - `calcTemp = new Calculations(query, 200)`

Comment: Well I feel like a complete idiot. I have been trying to get this parallel for loop working all day and I don't think it is working because I need my calculations to be performed in order and I believe the parallel for loop works on items with a random order. Is there anyway I can get the power of parallel computing and have it completed in order or am I screwed?

Comment: Being run in parallel means the calculation must produce the same result, regardless of which order each iteration is executed in. If your calculations are sequential, then you probably won't be able to run it in parallel

Comment: I'm afraid that most of my calculations are sequential so do I not have any options to make the calculations run faster?

Comment: There is still a possibility that some parts of it could be run in parallel, however I can't say without seeing at least some psuedo-code of the calculation you are attempting to speed up. Keep in mind that making an operation run in parallel is not the only way to optimize performance - have you tried profiling the calculation, and seeing which parts of the code are actually bottlenecking the operation?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
... (listMRInfo) = new ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>() ...
```

There are no overloads of `Parallel.For` whose third parameter accepts `T`, and the best match is this one:

```
Parallel.For<TLocal> Method (Int32, Int32, Func<TLocal>, Func<Int32, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal>, Action<TLocal>)
```

And, as the error says, `TLocal` cannot be implicitly converted to `Func<TLocal>`. As that parameter makes no sense because `listMRInfo` was already assigned, you should just do:

```
Parallel.For<ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>>(0, 200, (j, loop, listMRInfoLocal) => 
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: When I change my code to that it now says No overload for method For takes 4 arguments

Comment: Then you did something wrong, my answer has only 3 arguments.

Comment: All I did was copy and paste what you wrote. I deleted the ConcurrentBag<MultipleRegressionInfo>> and that took away the error but I just changed the code back to a simple parallel for loop and I'm back to getting the same errors that caused me to try these new methods. Multithreading in C# is the bane of my existence and I just feel like I'm going in circles :(